# How to open a url in safari in ios9

Tags: facebook, cocoa-touch, safari, ios9, url-scheme

I'have used the following code to redirect the user to a facebook page.

```
NSURL *webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://m.facebook.com/icc"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:webURL];
```

After updating to ios9, the above code is not working.

I have added following block in plist file. But not working.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>twitter</string>
    <string>whatsapp</string>
    <string>wechat</string>
    <string>line</string>
    <string>instagram</string>
    <string>kakaotalk</string>
    <string>mqq</string>
    <string>vk</string>
    <string>mqq</string>
</array>
```

Is anything i missed here?

Answer (score 0):

There are two `URL` related methods that are available. `canOpenURL` and `openURL`.

`canOpenURL` returns a yes or no answer after checking if there is any apps installed on the device that know how to handle a given URL.

`openURL` is used to actually launch the URL, which will typically leave the app and open the URL in another app.

And in your case i have tried the same code its working fine for me i means in case of `canOpenURL` its returning `YES` and when i call `openURL` its opening the `safari` and yes its same what you did.

For all developers having the same issue, the solution is to add a `whitelist` of all `URL` schemes your App may need to call into the `Info.plist`. The key to add is `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` and its value is an array with all the `URL` schemes.

Comment: i have added the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in plist file. But i still facing the problem. I have added the scheme list in question.

Comment: please validate are you trying `openURL` ? coz as i defined in that case there is not need to add `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` it will work with out as well. and `canOpenURL` only return bool value that will show you whether URL’s scheme can be handled by some app installed on the device.